# Save jQuery changes to css file on server

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm developing a system that allows for changing some of the css parameters without accessing the code. To achieve that I have `jQuery` objects like sliders and draggers which influence how the site looks user side, eg. `$("#MainContent").css("width", "55%");`. Now I need a way to append those changes to a .css file on the server.

Let me clarify that this is sort of a CMS system, and only administrator of the system would have this option, not the visitors of user-end site. I realise that .css is one for all users.

Ideal solution would connect to the server every time user makes a change, and replace only one line of css code. But I have no idea how to do it efficiently or if it at all possible.

Comment: not simple due to ranking order of css rules... making inline changes such as done with `$.css()` have highest priority. So if there are 4 other rules with that same selector....pretty hard to know what to change in files. And changing where `#MainContent` shares a rule not dimension related with `#Sidebar` ...adding `width` could screw up whole layout

Comment: I'm taking care of pixel to percentage correction and of adjusting other elements accordingly to fill the 'white space' in my JavaScript / jQuerry code. I just need to save all those changes into the css, while keeping all that's unchanged. So if I changed width of one element, I'm overwriting width of it and it's neighbours but I'm leaving alone their background colour, text font etc. and all other properties of all other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar

- in css files i replace properties values by a string like `width : PAGE_WIDTH_`
- in a page.INI file I have PAGE_WIDTH = "960px" (i looked at many solution but I chose this one over saving json object for example because of the ease to edit those manually as well)
- on request of a page php look for a cached css file for the site, if not found php opens the css files, replace the PAGE_WIDTH_ & other parameters with the value it finds in the INI files
- admin can change value of INI files through a simple interface ( which is pretty easy to do just iterate through all the properties in the INI file) & keep multiple theme as well & switch from one to the other; upon an edit of one of the INI files, php delete the cached css file to force the system to update the css of the site at next page request

here you go, quite some work, great benefits (like theme management, no parsing the css files, add new editable property in a blink...)

Comment: I've tried all things proposed and your solution fits my script the most. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome -> `parse_ini_file`

Answer (score 1):

You might use [less](http://lesscss.org) for this (or some other preprocessor that has client side support).  I've never done anything like this, but it would be quite possible and might work for you.

If you've never used a CSS preprocessor you might want to google up on the subject first before proceeding.

The basic idea would be to use variables for any data you want to be admin-modifiable.  These would be persisted server-side (in a database, likely), then used to generate a separate "variables" less file.  Note that because `less` needs this file to compile, it must be generated and saved to disk:

```
/* variables.less */
@mainContentWidth: 55%;
```

Then likely, some sort of generated mapping javascript/JSON mapping, which would be used to populate your form controls:

```
/* variables.js */
window.LESSVARS = {
  // `type` here totally just an idea, but the idea is that a "percentage"
  // field might be controlled with a slider, etc.
  mainContentWidth: { value: "55%", type: "percentage" }
}
```

For the rest of your CSS, whether you use the other features of less is up to you, but key part here is that you use the variables you defined where applicable:

```
/* styles.less */
@import "variables.less";    
#MainContent { width: @mainContentWidth; }
```

The general public will never see any of this, as they'll be served a compiled `styles.css` which puts it all together, simply:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

But the admin, on the other hand, will receive the uncompiled less and the mapping javascript object, which will be used to build your form controls and maintain state:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="variables.less" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="variables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, when the admin manipulates the form controls, instead of inlining styles with jQuery, you instead update the page via `less.modifyVars`:

```
// something like this, which updates the less variable state and then
// sends it to less which will recompile the CSS.  Note that this is
// just a simple example.  In the real version you'd probably want to
// track changes, etc.
function setVar(name, value) {
  LESSVARS[name].value = val;
  var o = {};
  o['@'+name] = value;
  less.modifyVars(o);
}

// which you'd then call on form control change
setVar('mainContentWidth', '30%');
```

Finally, once the admin wants to persist their changes, they'd submit the altered state for saving.  This might be the whole `LESSVARS` object or just the tracked changes.  On the server side, you'd store those changes and trigger a rewrite of `variables.less` and a recompilation of `styles.less`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are not many admins you shouldn't really worry about making it extremely efficient.

In the place where you call `$("#MainContent").css("width", "55%");` you should also place the code that will update the server.

So you would have a function like:

```
function updateServer(data){
    // data would probably be a JSON array with the changes to be made
    // Something like {element : {attribute1 : value1, attribute2 : value2}}
    $.post(...);
}
```

And then in the place where you were using .css() you will call the function to also update the server.

If there are many parameters that can be changed and you want to avoid sending too many POST requests you could also build a big `data` object, appending on every call to updateServer() and then use a Save button or a timer to send it to the server.

---

Now in the server you will have to implement some logic to parse this JSON data and edit a CSS file accordingly. I think the simplest would be to store all the values per attribute in a database or readable text file, and rebuild the CSS file from there.

I don't know what server-side language you are using but it shouldn't be too hard.